# Plugin incompatible with the new build found: Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I was going to upgrade from Android Studio Bumblebee to Android Studio Dolphin. However, I seem to get an unexpected warning from Android Studio:

[image: Android Studio Warning Image]

As you can see the text in red, it shows that newer Android Studio's build does not support Kotlin! However, in details of Android Studio Dolphin, and image shows Kotlin files being programmed, which means Android Studio Dolphin's build actually supports Kotlin:

[image: Android Studio Dolphin Details Page Image]

Should I update or not, and how should I fix this error, as I am a Kotlin Programmer.
Can somebody please help? Would appreciate it.

**Edit**

As for the Kotlin version, I have the latest Kotlin Version already:

[image: Kotlin Version Image]

Comment: If I am wrong, then somebody could please help me? And how to resolve this error. If somebody has faced this problem and resolved it, please help.

Comment: Hi, I faced with the same issue and after research I found people say that reinstalling Kotlin plugin or removing it and update Studio should solve the issue, because Dolphin already includes the Kotlin plugin by default. Personally I ignored this issue.  Works well :) Good luck

Comment: So, I should just press upgrade and ignore the warning? If yes, then post your comment as an answer so I can mark your answer as correct

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Full answer:

I faced with the same issue and after research I found people say that reinstalling Kotlin plugin or removing it and update Studio should solve the issue, because Dolphin already includes the Kotlin plugin by default.

BUT For sure you should NOT remove the Kotlin plugin, because otherwise Android Studio will fail launching and after that you need to find on your PC the file named 'disabled_plugins.txt' and remove from it Kotlin. OR completely remove Android Studio and reinstall it from the scratch.

Personally I ignored this issue and just updated the Studio. Works well and Kotlin plugin installed. Also I noticed that before update I had Kotlin version 1.7.10 and AS didn't ask for update the plugin. After update I've got 1.7.20.

Good luck :)

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll try and then mark your answer.

Comment: Same thing here, I did not disable anything, just ignored the warning, upgraded to Dolphin, and as Dmitriy said, after the upgrade, the `Kotlin` version is also updated to `1.7.20`

Comment: I think, Dolphin also automatically update kotlin plugin, Android studio update should not give the warning here.

Comment: Whatever the reason was, it worked by just directly clicking update without deleting the kotlin plugin. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The only option I have to "ignore" the error is to download the latest version of Android. When I do that and attempt to install it, Windows tries to install a second android studio program instead of replacing the original. Anybody have a suggestion on how to handle this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. If you are updating through settings in android studio, then there shouldn't be a second program installed. If you are talking about an installer and reinstalling with a fresh start, use the installer to install and I'm quite sure that the installer shows an option at end when finally launching android studio to delete older versions, so it should work. Multiple android studios has only happened with me when the previous version is a beta or canary and the installer is of stable version, or vice versa.