# Unable to update Android Studio because of Kotlin plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

When I attempt to update Android Studio (Arctic Fox to Electric Eel), I get an error message

> Plugin incompatible with the new build found: Kotlin

The only option it gives me is to download the new version of Android Studio. If I download the software and attempt to install it, it doesn't overwrite the previous version of Android Studio, instead it attempts to install a second version. The Kotlin plugin is up-to-date and if I uninstall it, I'm concerned it will cause more issues because so many other things depend on it.

Are there any steps I can take to enable the update button instead of the download button?

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are there any steps I can take to enable the update button instead of the download button?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that someone have had a similar issue, but with another version of Android Studio, here

[plugin-incompatible-with-the-new-build-found-kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74071136/plugin-incompatible-with-the-new-build-found-kotlin)